# Hello World Servlet Programming 404 Not found

Tags: servlets, http-status-code-404

Folder Structure

**/usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/test**

I have put the class file in 
**/usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/test/WEB_INF/classes**

web.xml in

**/usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/test/WEB_INF**

**Tomcat installation path** : 
/usr/share/tomcat7/

echo $CLASSPATH

/usr/share/tomcat7/lib/servlet-api.jar:

Compiled Java File

```
**sudo javac HelloWorld.java   -classpath /usr/share/tomcat7/lib/servlet-api.jar**
```

When I tried to access

```
http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld

http://localhost:8080/test/HelloWorld
```

Apache tomcat server works , I checked it by executing

```
**http://localhost:8080**
```

in browser

I get a **HTTP Status 404 - /HelloWorld**

Am I missing any configuration??Pl help

Comment: Do you configure your web.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

1.make a simple index.jsp page and copy it to `/usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/test/`. Type `http://localhost:8080/test/` in your browser. Does it show your index.jsp page? If yes goto next level.

2.Your web.xml file should contains mapping to your servlet:

```
<web-app>
    ......
    <servlet>
         <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
         <servlet-class>HelloWorld</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/HelloWorld</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: I have tried the above steps but  still getting                   HTTP Status 404 - /HelloWorld

Comment: @SowmyaManmathan: What is the result? Could you see index.jsp page?